# Error install istio in GKE = the server could not find the requested resource (post `gatewaies.networking.istio.io`)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have the following error when installing istio in GKE

kubernetes ver = `1.11.2-gke.18`
Istio ver = 1.0.4
Kubectl = latest from repo google

```
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating 
"`install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml`": 
the server could not find the requested resource
(post `gatewaies.networking.istio.io`)
```

I have tried to follow the tutorial on GCP:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio

Comment: I tried the GCP [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio) alike you for Istio using GKE and Node both with the same version as 1.11.2-gke.18. I used Istio version 1.0.4. It worked for me seamlessly. I would recommend you to file a defect report at Public Issue Tracker under Kubernetes Engine so that a detailed investigation can be done. Here is the [URL](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for filing defect report.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `CustomResourceDefinition` required by istio and hence getting this error. You need to apply following command from istio folder:

```
kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml
```

This will create all the CRD's like virtualservice, destinationrules etc.

Try following official documentation of Istio to install it on GKE:

> https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start-gke-dm/

Comment: i try, its still error

kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml

bla bla bla ...


kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml

kubernetes "attributes" configured
destinationrule "istio-policy" configured
destinationrule "istio-telemetry" configured
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource (post gatewaies.networking.istio.io)

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this issue when installing a custom Istio helm chart:

```
[tiller] 2019/11/15 21:50:52 failed install perform step: release test failed: the server could not find the requested resource (post gatewaies.networking.istio.io)
```

I've confirmed the Istio CRDs are installed properly. Note how the installed Gateway CRD explicitly notes the accepted plural name:

```
status:
  acceptedNames:
    categories:
    - istio-io
    - networking-istio-io
    kind: Gateway
    listKind: GatewayList
    plural: gateways
    shortNames:
    - gw
    singular: gateway
```

I created an [issue on Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6984) to see if that is the culprit, otherwise, I can open an issue on Istio to see if that is either. I'm very confused where the source of this issue could be coming from.

**Note: ** The type of the Gateway resource *is correct:*

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
```

Answer (score -2):

istio works by defining a series of crds(Custom Resource Definition), for istio to work, you first need to run command like this:

> kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml

for my version(istio v1.2.0), the command is

> for i in install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init/files/crd*yaml; do kubectl apply  -f $i; done

but as I follow the instructions from the documentatino, I still get the annoying messages:

```
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource (post gatewaies.networking.istio.io)
```

as the hint implies, the requested resource "gatewaies.networking.istio.io" cannot be found, and then I list the crds:

> kubectl get crd

and I got a list like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRCzF.png)

as I see inspect this, I find something wrong.
the message issued by kubectl is (post gatewaies.networking.istio.io), but the crd enlisted is post gateways.networking.istio.io, then everything is clear, the kubectl CLI issued a wrong plural for word "gateway", the correct form is gateways, instead of gatewaies, so to satisfy the command form, the crd must change.
And I edit this file:

> vim install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init/files/crd-10.yaml

by changing the name from "gateways.networking.istio.io" to "gatewaies.networking.istio.io", everything is ok now.

Comment: Changing the CRD seems kind of hacky and unsafe, especially if it isn't the culprit in the issue?